# Detect scanner input using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, barcode, onkeydown

Suppose I have two textboxes:

```
<input type="text"id="resourceName" placeholder="Resource name"/>
<input type="text" id="barCode"  placeholder="barCode(EAN-13)"/>
```

To populate this textboxes I use **barcode** scanner and keyboard.
What I want is a little bit difficult and I don't know how to do this .
I can't differentiate when user is populating text boxes with keyboard and when with barcode.
I need this becouse i want to implement something like : when user is usign barcode scanner and if we don't have focused textbox ,I want to focus barcode textbox and insert this value in this textbox , and when focused is resourceName textbox , first I want to focus barCode textbox and then to insert this value to this textbox.
I don't want to let user insert barcode in resourceName textbox using barcode scanner .
The problem is that i can't differentiate events , how user is populating textboxex ?, using barcode scanner or using keyboard.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps with a button somewhere that says "Begin Scanning" and when clicked the correct input box is focused and they know the program is ready to receive input.

Comment: You could capture all key presses for the document and, if they match the barcode format you could push them into the correct field.  Just check that the last 13 key presses were all digits and, if so, assume it was a barcode.  It's not perfect, but I think it's the best you'll get.

Answer (score 3):

Going off the idea I suggested in the comments, I came up with this...

```
var _keybuffer = "";

$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    _keybuffer += String.fromCharCode(code).trim();
    // trim to last 13 characters
    _keybuffer = _keybuffer.substr(-13);

    if (_keybuffer.length == 13) {
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(_keybuffer))) {
            barcodeEntered(_keybuffer);
            _keybuffer = "";
        }
    }
});

function barcodeEntered(value) {
    alert("You entered a barcode : " + value);
}
```

It keeps a buffer of the last 13 keys pressed and if it's just numbers then it assumes it's a barcode and triggers the `barcodeEntered` function.  This is obviously a hack and assumes that there is no reason anyone would ever type a 13 figure number elsewhere on the page (but you could make it ignore key presses if certain fields had focus etc..)

It captures all key presses on the page, regardless of focus so it should capture you scanning a barcode even when nothing has focus.

**Edit:** I've added `.trim()` to the keyboard buffering so that spaces are ignored, as per suggestion from @DenisBorisov.

Comment: Good but It is firing twice ?

Comment: @Erdogan It sounds like you've assigned the handler twice.

Comment: You also need to add line "_keybuffer = _keybuffer.trim();" after "_keybuffer += String.fromCharCode(code);". This is necessary for ignoring white spaces and \n symbols you scanner can send.

Comment: @DenisBorisov Good call - I've added that to the code.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at github [jQuery-Scanner-Detection](https://github.com/escaleno-ltda/jQuery-Scanner-Detection)

[NPM Package jQuery-Scanner-Detection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jQuery-Scanner-Detection)

jQuery Scanner Detection is a small plugin to detect when user use a scanner (barcode, QR Code...) instead of a keyboard, and call specific callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at jQuery's [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event

Bind this to your input box and it'll alert you when a user is using their keyboard for barcode input

Also, have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621299/jquery-listening-for-automated-scanner-input-from-keyboard?rq=1)?

Comment: I did it but nothig good ...This is not enough to make difference ...
This is main problem they have same keypress event.

Comment: @nicuJanga Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621299/jquery-listening-for-automated-scanner-input-from-keyboard?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the solutions, but not worked as expected. I found very easiest solution onscan.js I have application using angular 8.

Very simple and good implementation.

For angular 8, I followed steps:

1.npm install onscan.js --save

2.open angular.json, add one entry to script array as "node_modules/onscan.js/onscan.min.js"

3.In component class, implement interface AfterViewInit

```
declare var onscan:any;
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    //Put focus to textbox and press scanner button
    onScan.attachTo(document, {
      suffixKeyCodes: [13], // enter-key expected at the end of a scan
      reactToPaste: true, // Compatibility to built-in scanners in paste-mode (as opposed to keyboard-mode)
      onScan: function (sCode, iQty) { // Alternative to document.addEventListener('scan')
        console.log('Scanned: ' + iQty + 'x ' + sCode);
      },
    });
  }
```

Best thing is scanned text appears into focued textbox element

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @Reinstate Monica Cellio I came up with this example which works great for me and my barcode scanner. I cannot limit the input to 13 characters since it's a 2D scanner that will also have to scan S/N QR codes containing text and with different lengths.

```
    var _keybuffer = "";
    var _keybufferTime = 0;
    function detectBarCode(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        var isEnter = code == 13;

        if (_keybufferTime == 0) {
            _keybufferTime = Date.now();
            if (isEnter) {
                return false;
            } else {
                _keybuffer += String.fromCharCode(code).trim();
            }
        } else {
            var currentTime = Date.now();
            var timeBetween = currentTime - _keybufferTime;
            console.log("Time between inputs: " + timeBetween);
            if (timeBetween > 50) {
                // Reset the keybuffer
                _keybuffer = "";
            }
            _keybufferTime = currentTime;

            if (!isEnter) {
                _keybuffer += String.fromCharCode(code).trim();
            } else {
                var bufferCopy = (' ' + _keybuffer).slice(1);
                barcodeEntered(bufferCopy);
                _keybuffer = "";
                _keybufferTime = 0;
            }
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return true;
    }

    function barcodeEntered(value) {
        alert("You entered a barcode : " + value);
    }
```