# Automatically submitting a HTML form after scanning a barcode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to automatically submit a form after scanning a barcode. The number I scan is always 16 digits long.

```
<form id="Form" action="action.php" method="post">
  <input id="here" maxlength="16" placeholder="scan..." type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
  <input id="subHere" type="submit">
</form>

<script>
  $('#here').keyup(function(){
    if(this.value.length ==16){
    $('#subHere').click();
    }
  });
</script>​
```

The restriction of entering 16 digits is working but my form is not automatically submitting after entering the 16 digits.

I also want to clear the form after submitting, so I can scan the next barcode. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is that all of your `<form>` ? It has no `action` and I don't see a 'click` event being set, so it won't submit anywhere.

Comment: Normaly Barcord machin facilitated to "press enter" after scan. Didn't you try to do with that feture?

Comment: my barcode scanner is acting like it is a keyboard, I've tried touse it this way but I do not have this feature

Comment: You are currently sending your form to # which does not do anything. Have you build some code that handles the form after submitting?

Comment: You are right. I've added the action and eddited my script, but I still have to click manually to submit.

Comment: I posted an answer on a similar question a while ago.  See if this helps... https://stackoverflow.com/a/19959352/1023618

Comment: With the updated HTML for form, your code should work. If it doesn't there should be a problem somewhere else. Is that all the `JS` you have on the page? Did you try the browser console to see if there is an error? Try putting an `alert()` inside your `if()` block to see if it is executing at all

Comment: Working [here](http://jsbin.com/yaqejijise/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thank you @Fr0zenFyr, it's working now

Comment: Glad it's working.. :) do you mind posting the solution if not already posted by someone here.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Fr0zenFyr it is working now:

```
<form id="Form" action="./js/filehandling.js" method="post">
   <input id="here" maxlength="16" placeholder="scan..." type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
   <input id="subHere" type="submit">
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

<script>
  $('#here').keyup(function(){
      if(this.value.length ==16){
      $('#subHere').click();
      }
  });
</script>​
```

after entering 16 digits, it automatically submits the form

Comment: Just wanted to point out that `<input id="subHere" type="submit" id="submit">` is not valid `html`. it should have only one `id`. In general, modern browsers will ignore all additional `id` attributes on an element, but you never know what might break. Based on the use of id in your `javascript`, you can get rid of `id="submit"`

Comment: You are right, I've noticed that, I will edit my post

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be :

```
<script>
  $("#input_field").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length >= 16)
      $('#form').submit();
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried your code, but I must have another mistake in my code. It is still not submitting after entering the 16 digits

Comment: Is there any Error ? Have included the jquery File ?